# How I can get transform Promise to something like a list?

Tags: json, angular, authentication, promise, angular2-services

I am new to dealing with Angle 2 I have developed a service REST API that returns me a JSON string. Which makes the request is the following code:

```
getUsuaris(): Promise<Usuari> {
    return this.http.get(this.URLUsuaris)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Usuari[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The following code is a simple login, without more, but not because the authenticatedUserList reason is NULL and obiamente its attributes.

```
private URLUsuaris = 'http://localhost:50541/api/Usuaris';

constructor(
    private _logger: Logger,
    private _router: Router,
    private http: Http) { }

logIn(usuari: Usuari) {

    var authenticatedUserList: Promise<Usuari> = this.getUsuaris();
    var authenticatedUser: Usuari;

    this._logger.log(authenticatedUserList[0]);

    for (var i in authenticatedUserList) {
        if (authenticatedUserList[i].usuari === usuari.Usuari1) {
            authenticatedUser = authenticatedUserList[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (authenticatedUser && authenticatedUser.Password === usuari.Password){
        localStorage.setItem("usuari", authenticatedUser.Usuari1);
        this._router.navigate(['Home']);

        this._logger.log(localStorage.getItem("usuari"));
        this._logger.log('Usuari Registart!');

        return true;
    }
    this._logger.log('Usuari No Registart!');
    return false;
}
```

The server with the REST API returns the information correctly!

User class which is what sends the API:

```
export class Usuari {
    public Id: number;
    public Usuari1: string;
    public Password: string;

    constructor(usuari: string, password: string) { }
}
```

Please if you have any idea what might be failing an explanation not be obliged to meet the same mistake in the future.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the return of the promise like this:

```js
private URLUsuaris = 'http://localhost:50541/api/Usuaris';

constructor(
    private _logger: Logger,
    private _router: Router,
    private http: Http) { }

logIn(usuari: Usuari) {
 return this.getUsuaris().then((authenticatedUserList)=>{
  var authenticatedUser: Usuari;

  this._logger.log(authenticatedUserList[0]);

  for (var i in authenticatedUserList) {
   if (authenticatedUserList[i].usuari === usuari.Usuari1) {
    authenticatedUser = authenticatedUserList[i];
    break;
   }
  }

  if (authenticatedUser && authenticatedUser.Password === usuari.Password){
   localStorage.setItem("usuari", authenticatedUser.Usuari1);
   this._router.navigate(['Home']);

   this._logger.log(localStorage.getItem("usuari"));
   this._logger.log('Usuari Registart!');

   return true;
  }
  this._logger.log('Usuari No Registart!');
  return false;
 });
}
```

This also changed the return of the logIn method so that now it returns a `Promise<boolean>` instead of `boolean`.